# bind function dynamically on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, bind

I'm been working on this and it's driving me crazy D:

So, i have this code:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover" id="tbl_indicaciones">
<thead><tr>
<th>INDICACIÓN FARMACOLÓGICA</th><th>POSOLOGÍA</th><th>REALIZADO</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="txt_posologia"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And:

```
$(".txt_posologia").blur(function(){
    guardarIndicacion($(this));
});

var guardarIndicacion = function(elemento){
    //REVISAR QUE LOS CAMPOS TENGAN VALORES
    var indicacion = $(elemento).parent().parent().find('td:eq(0)').find('input:eq(0)');
    if(indicacion.val() == "" || $(elemento).val() == ""){
        alert("Debe ingresar ambos campos");
        indicacion.focus();
    }else{
        //REVISO SI SOY EDITABLE
        if($(elemento).attr("data-editable") != "false"){
            //HAGO ALGO
            //AGREGO LINEA A TABLA
            try{$("#tbl_indicaciones").find('tbody').
                append($('<tr>').
                    append($('<td>').html("<input type=\"text\">")).
                    append($('<td>').html("<input type=\"text\" class=\"txt_posologia\">").on('blur', function() {guardarIndicacion($(this))}))
                );}catch(e){alert(e.toString)}
            //ME HAGO NO EDITABLE
            $(elemento).attr("data-editable", "false");
        }
    }
}
```

So, everytime that my "inputs .txt_posologia" lost focus it add a new line on my table.
This work with the first input defined on my page, but it doesn't on the new ones ...

Thanks !

Just in case, a little [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G8SM6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your example working:
http://jsfiddle.net/GR5sJ/

```
$( document ).on( "blur", ".txt_posologia", function() {
  guardarIndicacion($(this));
});
```

For handling this kind of dynamic generated fields it's good to use the jquery 'on' For more documentation here:
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Mucha suerte!

Comment: Holy frak ... just missed one parameter ... ok then .. leasson learned ;) +1 thanks for the link.

Suerte para ti también :) Gracias Totales

Answer (score 3):

If by the "new ones" you mean dynamically generated inputs, then it's because you need event delegation:

```
$(document).on('blur', '.txt_posologia', function(){
    guardarIndicacion($(this));
});
```

Comment: Carter is right, but I figured I would add a bit of info to the why.

You attach the blur event handler to the class .txt_posologia. It only runs once on page load, so additional classes are not bound to that event. So you have to attach the listener at the document level, so when the document is changed with can be bound to the event.

Comment: Preferably I attach event handlers to the nearest parent which will be available on document load, but attaching to document should always be safe.  Well said Duane